# Why almost same MySQL queries takes different times to execute?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, time, profiling

I have enable the profiler on Codeigniter. So I can see times taken buy different queries.

These queries are run via a loop. Queries are almost same. Please check the screenshot. I have highlight those same queries in below screenshot.

Even though queries are almost same **some quieres  3 times slower than other queries**. But queries are almost same.

What is the reason for it?

[image]

**Update :** A user has asked the table structure via comment. So I added the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `property_meta` (
  `pm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pro_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fea_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pm_value` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `property_meta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pm_id`),
  ADD KEY `pro_id` (`pro_id`),
  ADD KEY `fea_id` (`fea_id`);

ALTER TABLE `property_meta`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `property_meta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pro_id`) REFERENCES `property` (`pro_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `property_meta_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`fea_id`) REFERENCES `feature` (`fea_id`);
```

Comment: did u add indexing on ur table ?

Comment: Are you concerned because the volumes are the same for every query? Also why set columns (to the same values) which are used in the where statement?

Comment: @XMozart Yes, I have indexed. I updated the question with the table structure also now.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, quiries are same but some queries takes 3 times that some queries. That is my problem.  I am sorry, I did not get what you asked in second part.

Comment: Will the same query always take a  longer time, or is it only few *random* queries among your loop that are slower?

Comment: @Antony Same query does not take a longer time every time. It change on every time.

Comment: I'm guessing the fast results are cached results, or that your computer had more ressources available when doing these queries.